# Detect changes in ngModel in combination with setter and getter

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m having problems with a one of my components. The (shortended) Code looks as follows:

```
 export class SampleComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
      @Input('options') public innerOptions: any[] = [];  
      @Input('value') public innerValue: any = null;
      @Input() public config: ListConfigModel = new ListConfigModel();  

      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
      }

  public ngOnInit() {    
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.options);
  } 

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);    
  }

  public get options(): any {
    let emptyEntry: any = (this.allowEmptyValue) ? [this.emptyEntry] : [];
    let validOptions = emptyEntry.concat((this.innerOptions !== null) ? this.innerOptions : []);

    return validOptions;
  }

  public set options(options: any) {
    this.innerOptions = options;
  }

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  set value(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.onValueSelected();
    }
  }

  public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;      
    }
  }
}
```

The component is called inside another component with

```
<sample [(ngModel)]="currentEntity.value" [options]="options"></sample>
```

The value parameter is a plain parameter of a object inside the parent component while the options are a subscription.
Now to my problem:
When my sampleComponent is inizialized, the value is null but the options are aviable. if the ngOnChanges triggers the first time, value is still null, and just an empty array is passed inside. When ngOnChanges is called the second and last time, the options are set to actual array with data but value is still null. Some time later, the value seemingly magic jumps to the correct value from the parent component. writeValue is triggered but it doesn´t gets detected. So my question is how to detect when value changes from null to an actual value. I am trying to build some string out of it as soon as it appears. tried to use ngDoCheck but this messed up my performance. also tried to trigger the string building function inside writeValue which causes infinite loops.

**So please tell me how to detect the changes in value**

Comment: Have you tried `[value]="currentEntity.value"`?

Comment: The goal is to use the 'banana-in-the-box' to directly set the value inside the samleComponent and to detect changes inside the Samplecomponent. Therefore I am reluctantly using value to pass the parameters in

Comment: If you want to make a "custom form control" this must extends of ControlValueAccessor, export class SampleComponent extends ValueAccessorBase<string>, see e.g. http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/

Comment: @Eliseo Yeah I have all the functions inside my actual code but still having problems with the detection of changes in ngModel from outside

Comment: John, your class NOT extends from ValueAccesorBase (only have a write function), Don't import NG_VALUE_ACCESOR... other link more simple https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html